# Dual problemn -> what to do with summand in objective function not connected to variable

Tags: linear-programming

say I have the simple primal problem
$$
\text{max } Z = 3x_1 + 2x_2 -7
$$
s.t.
\begin{align*}
3x_1 + 5x_2 &\ge 6 \\
7x_1 + 55 x_2 &\ge 44 \\
x_1,x_2 &\ge 0
\end{align*}
Now would I be able to use the summand $-7$ is the dual problem? Where does it belong there and why?

Thank you in advance and have a wonderful day. :)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

Since $-7$ is not linked to any variable, it will always be added to the objective function.

So you can simply add $-7$ to the dual objective function.